# How can I ensure that the file output from a DataContractSerializer is a "regularly" formatted XML?

Tags: xml, serialization

Every time I output XML from a DataContractSerializer, it's a single line XML string.  This is valid XML, but it's a pain to read.  How can I get additional whitespace added in there to break out elements into tabbed lines?

```
public void Save(Stream stream)
{
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<PlottingDeviceInfo>));
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, this.Devices);
}
```

Comment: Use a text editor? Maybe open it in Visual Studio and use "Format Document"?

Comment: I meant as part of the output process O_O

Comment: Surely it will depend on what code you use to do your output, so surely you should post some code?

Comment: I don't see that it matters, it's the DataContractSerializer's output...

Comment: You ask for help, then ignore what the helpers ask for. Interesting. Turns out that it has nothing to do with the `DataContractSerializer`.

Comment: well seeing as I'm using it, it certainly does have something to do with it :-P but I posted code as asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`WriteObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms573855.aspx) overload that takes an `XmlWriter`, then pass it an `XmlWriter` configured to produce pretty output.

```
public void Save(Stream stream)
{
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<PlottingDeviceInfo>));
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, new XmlWriterSettings{Indent=true}))
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(writer, this.Devices);
    }
}
```

When you just use a `Stream`, `WriteObject` creates it's own, default `XmlWriter`. It's the `XmlWriter` that determines the format, etc.